# Powershell Hyper-V Scripts won't work? + Auto Installing Windows

Tags: powershell, automation, hyper-v

So I have a strange problem. When I do commands such as this:

```
New-VM -Name "MattTest" -MemoryStartupBytes 2GB -BootDevice CD -SwitchName Lab -path c:\VMdocs -NewVHDSizeBytes 40GB –NewVHDPath c:\base.vhdx

Set-VMDvdDrive -VMName MattTest -Path C:\ISOFiles\Windows2008.

Start-VM -Name MattTest
```

It works fine, However if I make a script I get a TON of errors, for example the exact same thing in a script called PS.ps1 and ran through Powershell I get:

> New-VM : The parameter is not valid. No switch can be found by given
>   criteria. At C:\Users\mrsmith\Desktop\PS.ps1:1 char:1
>   + New-VM -Name "MattTest" -MemoryStartupBytes 2GB -BootDevice CD -SwitchName Lab - ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Lab:String) [New-VM], VirtualizationInvalidArgumentException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidParameter,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.NewVMCommand
>
> Set-VMDvdDrive : The parameter is not valid. Hyper-V was unable to
>   find a virtual machine with name MattTest. At
>   C:\Users\mrsmith\Desktop\PS.ps1:3 char:1
>   + Set-VMDvdDrive -VMName MattTest -Path C:\ISOFiles\Windows2008.
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (MattTest:String) [Set-VMDvdDrive], VirtualizationInvalidArgumentExcept    ion
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidParameter,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.SetVMDvdDriveCommand
>
> Set-VMDvdDrive : The parameter is not valid. No DVD drives are found.
>   At C:\Users\mrsmith\Desktop\PS.ps1:3 char:1
>   + Set-VMDvdDrive -VMName MattTest -Path C:\ISOFiles\Windows2008.
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-VMDvdDrive], VirtualizationInvalidArgumentException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidParameter,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.SetVMDvdDriveCommand
>
> Start-VM : The parameter is not valid. Hyper-V was unable to find a
>   virtual machine with name MattTest. At
>   C:\Users\mrsmith\Desktop\PS.ps1:5 char:1
>   + Start-VM -Name MattTest
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (MattTest:String) [Start-VM], VirtualizationInvalidArgumentException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidParameter,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.StartVMCommand

Im not sure what's causing this? is it something to do with the module, because I have checked and the Hyper-V cmdlet IS running (considering I can manually type these in and they will be fine)

Also sidequestion: These set of instructions will get up to the "Install Windows XXXX" Screen. Is there any way to Automate THAT process? Or not really (Like make it click next, select a hard drive, install, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to make sure, the prompt (e.g 'PS C:\Users\mrsmith\Desktop>') is not a part of the script, right? If so remove it.

As it appears, it is a part of the script because `PS` is an alias for `Get-Process` and it tries to pass 'C:\Users\mrsmith\Desktop' as a process name.

Comment: Ooops Ya my bad, it's not supposed to be it's just a mistake where I copied it from.

Comment: So, without the prompt the script runs as expected?

Comment: Are you a local admin on the machine in question? Is the shell elevated?

Comment: It is, actually I think I was having some sort of weird issue, so when I restarted I actually got different (and I think more correct) errors. I mean the Individual commands themselves work.....just when I put it in a script it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have a switch named 'lab'? Run Get-VMSwitch to find out

Comment: AH that was it, it was left over. Man am I dumb, everything else seemed to work now......Derp.